# Delete WooCommerce Analytics data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, privacy

I try to anonymize WooCommerce for debug access by third party plugin developers with a bash command line script on my linux server. I successfully could remove users and orders but now I discover that all the sales statistics are still available in WooCommerce' Analytics including names and figures. Where do I find this in database so I can include it my database query to address it?

By request I include here a screenshot of WC analytics' first page with sales and order reports, financial data not to be revealed to a plugin author. [image]

Comment: Started exploring the wp_options table and could remove user data from the Analytics with DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wc_report_%';

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `WooCommerce > Status > Tools  > Clear Analytics Cache` tool. Analytics dashboard is using a lot of caching, otherwise it would be too slow. Before clearing the cache, make sure you empty the orders from the trash too.

And while you are on the `WooCommerce > Status > Tools` page, delete all transients too.

Comment: I discovered the command line equivalents of these. I ran both to no effect. I also tried the web version of this without result. Still have my vote for your attempt, because I cannot withdraw it.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of the screen where you see the private data? You can blur the sensitive data.

Comment: screenshot was added to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the "delete all transients", didn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

i got this same problem and resolve it via SQL.
Try use this SQL to remove orders stored in WooCommerce analitics:

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE_PREFIX]_wc_order_stats;
DELETE FROM [TABLE_PREFIX]_wc_order_coupon_lookup;
DELETE FROM [TABLE_PREFIX]_wc_order_product_lookup;
```